# Scrapy output my item in single row

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I am having trouble with my spider to import result in csv and all my items on the output was in single row. Please help.

Here is my spider

```
import scrapy
from mudah.items import MudahItem

class MudahSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "mudah"
allowed_domain = ["mudah.my"]
start_urls = ["http://www.mudah.my/Perak/Properties-for-sale-2001?   lst=0&fs=1&w=106&cg=2001&so=1&st=s"]

def parse(self,response):
for row in response.xpath('//*[@id="list-view-ads"]'):    
item = MudahItem()
    item['Title'] = sel.xpath('//*/div/ul/li[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/h2[@class="list_title"]/a/text()').extract()
    item['Price'] = sel.xpath('//*/div/ul/li[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[@class="ads_price"]/text()').extract()
    yield item
```

Here is my output in csv

```
Price                             Title
RM 135 000,RM 361 000,.....       Title1, Title 2, Title 3,.......
```

I want the csv to output the items in list like below.

```
Price             Title
$ 135 000.        Title1
$ 1 080 000       Title2
$ 361 000         Title3
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: you just returned 1 item, which contains all the prices and titles together. Change it to output several items instead of 1

Answer (score -1):

Iterate over all rows one by one.

def parse(self,response):
    item = MudahItem()

```
for row in response.xpath("//*/div/ul/li[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]"):

    item['Title'] = sel.xpath('h2[@class="list_title"]/a/text()').extract()
    item['Price'] = sel.xpath('div/div[@class="ads_price"]/text()').extract()
    yield item
```